# Create Instagram Account Using C#

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

I am using [InstagramApiSharp](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp)

Here is my code :

```cs
        public static async void CreateAccount()
        {
            var _instaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder().Build();
            var email = "ramtinaaka@live.com";
            var username = "rmt40306";
            var password = "rmt122345678";
            var firstName = "Ramtiinnn";
            var checkEmail = await _instaApi.CheckEmailAsync(email);
            if(checkEmail.Succeeded && checkEmail.Value.Available)
            {
                var create = await _instaApi.CreateNewAccountAsync(username, password, email, firstName);
                if (create.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                
            }
            return;

        }
```

I get `Error` printed on console when I call `CreateAccount` method as well as no account created.

[Create Account Wiki](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/wiki/Create-new-account)

I believe I gave all needed info, I don't think there is anything else to add.

Comment: What type is `create`? I expect there are other properties which tell you exact error, e.g. if name is occupied or password doesn't fulfill security requirements. You have to find out what error you get.

Comment: It seems, that the Api gives you more informations of the error. So please check the response!

Comment: IANAL: _You can't attempt to create accounts or access or collect information in unauthorized ways. This includes creating accounts or collecting information in an automated way without our express permission._  [TOC](https://help.instagram.com/1215086795543252)

Comment: @Sinatr create.Info.Message gives me this `Update Instagram in the app store to sign up. Your version of the app is out of date.`

Comment: @TheTanic done, the response in the previous comment